# Use office-ui-fabric-js inside angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I have made a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hozajonelo/1/edit?html,output) with [office-ui-fabric-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js).

Now I would like to add an angular controller around. So I tried this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pifodovore/2/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.2.0/css/fabric.components.min.css">
  <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp">
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
    <div class="ms-CommandBar">
      <div class="ms-CommandBar-mainArea">
        <div class="ms-CommandButton">
          <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
            <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-themePrimary"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--CircleRing"></i></span><span class="ms-CommandButton-label">Command</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{haha}}
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">     
    var CommandBarElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-CommandBar");
    for (var i = 0; i < CommandBarElements.length; i++) {
        new fabric['CommandBar'](CommandBarElements[i]);
    }
    angular.module('YourApp', ['officeuifabric.core', 'officeuifabric.components'])
    .controller('YourController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.haha = true
    }])
  </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

However, it gives an error `Failed to instantiate module YourApp`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

By theory can we use `office-ui-fabric` and `office-ui-fabric-js` inside `angular`, or do we have to use `ng-office-ui-fabric`?

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you are trying to do here.  You *appear* to be trying to inject angularjs modules `'officeuifabric.core'` and `'officeuifabric.components'` into `YourApp`, but it doesn't look like these are angular modules.

Comment: Short answer is yes, you will either need to use `ng-office-ui-fabric`, or write your own implementation that makes these libraries angular-compatible.

Comment: `officeuifabric.core` and `officeuifabric.components` are angular modules. I have been injecting them like that, eg, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178137/width-of-contextual-menu).

Comment: right, but those **definately** are `ng-office-ui-fabric` modules.  They are not part of the non-angular script you are trying to inject in this sample.  Your question seems to ask how to *not* use the library that was designed to do the exact thing you are trying to accomplish, and you are continuing to try and inject the library even though you aren't including it.

Comment: OK... but is there a way to enable `<div ng-controller="YourController">...</div>` part in a code having angularjs?

Comment: I am asking this because sometimes i have trouble using `ng-office-ui-fabric` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304625/dont-hide-items-when-there-are-still-space).

Comment: what does " enable `<div ng-controller="YourController">...</div>` part in a code having angularjs?" even mean?  **In theory**, if you just removed the dependencies on `ng-office-ui-fabric`, (i.e. `angular.module('YourApp', [])`), your app will not throw errors anymore.  As far as using `office-ui-fabric`, you can certainly try using it without the angular support, but it's likely to be buggy, since it will be unable to tell angular when to update bindings.

Comment: I see... I just realise we can do bindings (ie, `{{...}}`), `ng-click` and `ng-show` with `office-ui-fabric` and `angularjs` like [here](https://jsbin.com/lojezudito/1/edit?html,output).... Then, in this case, what's the value-added of `ng-office-ui-fabric`?

Comment: it looks to me like it's just meant to be an implementation to help manage the interaction between the two libraries.  I don't have a lot of experience with the library to know what it adds or removes, but I was investigating your other question a bit.  it seems to me that what you are seeing in that question might be a bug that needs to be reported, but I am still working through it.

Comment: Cool, do you want to put an answer for this question? "if you just removed the dependencies on `ng-office-ui-fabric`, (i.e. `angular.module('YourApp', []))`, your app will not throw errors anymore. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-office-ui-fabric` is a module for Angular.js which is a wrapper around `office-ui-fabric`.  It is designed to give you AngularJs Directives that may make using `office-ui-fabric` easier.

In your code, you are still including the dependencies for this module, even though you aren't actually loading it.  Removing these dependencies in your app load, i.e. `angular.module('YourApp', [])` will fix your app and allow it to load properly.

Using the `office-ui-fabric` library in this way *might* be challenging, because any time you use JavaScript functions outside AngularJs, you have to manually execute a `$digest` cycle for AngularJs to know that values on the page have changed.  This *may or may not* be an issue with the `office-ui-fabric` library.

Comment: Is there a standard way to use `office-ui-fabric` JavaScript functions with AngularJS? Will moving all these JS functions inside the controller be better?

Comment: creating a directive for the non-angular code is the standard, which is why `ng-office-ui-fabric` is a series of directives.