# Don't hide items when there are still space

Tags: css, angularjs, office-ui-fabric

I am  trying to use the command bar of [ng-office-ui-fabric](http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/), here is a [code](https://jsbin.com/soyohajowi/2/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/2.6.3/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngOfficeUiFabric/0.15.3/ngOfficeUiFabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
      <uif-command-bar>
        <uif-command-bar-main>
          <uif-command-bar-item>
            <span>one</span>
          </uif-command-bar-item>
          <uif-command-bar-item>
            <span>two</span>
          </uif-command-bar-item>
          <uif-command-bar-item>
            <span>three</span>
          </uif-command-bar-item>
        </uif-command-bar-main>
      </uif-command-bar>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    angular.module('YourApp', ['officeuifabric.core', 'officeuifabric.components'])
    .controller('YourController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}])
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

If we change the width of the preview, we could see that the items are **hidden** very easily (we could see a class `is-hidden` is added), even though there are visually lots of space.

Does anyone know how to control this limit width such that the items are not hidden easily?

Another option is never hiding the command items, does anyone know how to enable this?

Otherwise, is it possible to make a command bar with `office-ui-fabric` in `angularjs` without `ng-office-ui-fabric`?

Comment: the code that is affecting your command bar is [here](https://github.com/ngOfficeUIFabric/ng-officeuifabric/blob/master/src/components/commandbar/commandBarDirective.ts#L317).  In essence, it is switching these items to "overflow" when in mobile layout (width < 640px).  there seems to be a toggle for "mobile switch" but I don't know at this second where that is set.

Comment: I have noticed that part too... I even made a version without the `angular.forEach(scope.commandItems,...` part. But it still did not work...